# When does the metric projection operator have a closed form?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization

I have a simple question. Often times in optimization, the following function is used:

Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space and $C$ a nonempty closed convex subset of $H$, then the metric projection is defined as the function,

$$P_C(x) = \text{argmin}_{y \in C} ||x - y||$$

Sometimes (not always), this function will have a closed form. For example, if $C$ is the interval $[-1,1]$ in $\mathbb{R}$, then $P_C(x) = \min(\max(x,-1),1)$.

Is there a pattern to when $P_C$ has a closed form versus when you have to solve it numerically?

Comment: In finite dimensions at least the formula for the distance to an ellipsoid is known. They use this quite a bit in geodesy.

Comment: @alvarezpaiva Ok. I am asking because currently what I see in optimization related research is a disclaimer: "$C$ has to be simple", but I do not quite understand what types of sets this "simple" definition encompass.

Comment: So the question is "for what convex bodies in a Hilbert space, besides affine subspaces and quadrics, does the projection function admit a closed form?" ?

Comment: That is one way to sharpen the question. yes

Comment: Say $C$ is a polytope, like a cube or a tetrahedron, in $n$-dimensions. Then the closed-form solution is to exhaustively enumerate all the corners, but most polytopes have an exponential number of corners (e.g. a hypercube has $2^n$ corners). On the other hand, a numerical algorithm can _exactly_ solve this projection as a quadratic program in $n^{3.5}$ time. Why look for a closed-form solution?

Comment: @RichardZhang What do you mean by *Exactly* ?

Comment: @EldacarHyarmendacil Short answer is No. Indeed, think of the proxy question *Does $C$ contain the origin ?* You can certainly form a convex set $C$ descriptively (say, defined as the intersection of infiitely many abstractly defined convex sets), for which the answer to that question is not the truth value of a predicate with an "analytic" form.

Comment: @dohmatob a numerical algorithm can find an exact solution, rather than simply an $\epsilon$-accurate one, in $O(n^{3.5})$ time. This is by rounding off the solution once $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small to reveal the active set.

Comment: Hum, any reference for this statement ? Also ,what "active set" are you talking about ? Remember, the question is about projection onto a closed convex set in an arbitrary Hilbert space.